# How to set the positions and size of custom XIB View into the main View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, addsubview

I made custom view class with xib and load this UIView Class from XIB. It shows this xib but not set the height and width as of UIView in the ViewController.swift.

[image: Output]

CustomView.swift

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(contentView)
    }

}
```

[image: CustomView.xib Image]

ViewController.Swift

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let customView = CustomView()
            customView.frame = view1.frame
            view1.addSubview(customView)
        }
    }
```

[image: ViewController Image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go here with a little bit different approach in the initialization of the custom view. Here is the code:

CustomView:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    class func instanceFromNibWithFrame(_ frame: CGRect) -> UIView {
        guard let view = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as ?UIView else {
            fatalError("CustomView can't be init")
        }
    view.frame = frame
    return view
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let customView = CustomView.instanceFromNibWithFrame(view1.bounds)
        view1.addSubview(customView)
    }
}
```